Python Programming assignment: I do not understand how to fix the error
Assignment: Assume the file numbers.txt contains a series of numbers. Write a program that calculates the average of all the negative numbers and the average of all the positive numbers, and then prints both to the screen. If there are no numbers (i.e. no negative numbers and/or no positive numbers), print NaN instead.
Print only the averages, first the negative and then the positive, with no formatting.
My code:
def calculate_averages(file_name):
    negatives = []
    positives = []
   
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            try:
                num = float(line.strip())
                if num < 0:
                    negatives.append(num)
                elif num > 0:
                    positives.append(num)
            except ValueError:
                continue  # Skip lines that are not valid numbers

    # Calculate the averages
    neg_avg = sum(negatives) / len(negatives) if negatives else float('NaN')
    pos_avg = sum(positives) / len(positives) if positives else float('NaN')
    
    # Print the averages
    print(neg_avg)
    print(pos_avg)

calculate_averages('numbers.txt')

Error message from "Pearson": Line 1 of output was expected to be NaN, but it was nan.
I do not understand how I am getting this wrong or how to fix it! Any help and advice is very much appreciated, thank you!

Replace ...else float('NaN') with ...else 'NaN'.

The automated checker of your assignment is expecting the string "NaN", you are giving it the float nan.

This! Fixed it, I knew it was something simple and stupid. Thank you!

I tested your code and it works fine :)
def calculate_averages(file_name):
  negatives = []
  positives = []
  with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
      for line in file:
          try:
              num = float(line.strip())
              if num < 0:
                  negatives.append(num)
              elif num > 0:
                  positives.append(num)
          except ValueError:
              continue

  neg_avg = sum(negatives) / len(negatives) if negatives else float('NaN')
  pos_avg = sum(positives) / len(positives) if positives else float('NaN')

  print(neg_avg)
  print(pos_avg)

calculate_averages('./1.txt')

// 1.txt
2
3

// Result
nan
2.5


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I think they just want you to
print("NaN")

Also, in your if statement, you may want to consider what happens when the value  of "num" is 0.
Hope this helps.
